# Go - Casting a dynamic struct into a parameterized interface struct

Tags: go, generics

I'm trying to introduce constrained types into my interface's methods, as so:

```
type Inputs interface {
    moduleA.ModuleAInputs | moduleB.ModuleBInputs
}

type Module[T Inputs] interface {
    Run(moduleInput T) error
}
```

When I try to initialize `ModuleA` (which should fulfill the `Module` interface):

```
type ModuleA struct {...}
type ModuleAInputs struct {...}
func (s *ModuleA) Run(moduleInput moduleAInputs) error {
    return nil
}
```

like so:

```
func ConvertDynamicModule[T Inputs](moduleType string, rawModuleAttributes json.RawMessage) (Module[T], ModuleType, error) {
    // Check for valid module type
    isValidTaskModuleType, taskModuleTypeCasted := IsValidModule(moduleType)
    if !isValidTaskModuleType {
        return nil, "", fmt.Errorf("invalid moduleType of %s", moduleType)
    }

    // Cast moduleAttributes into a concrete struct

    var concreteModule Module[T]
    switch taskModuleTypeCasted {
    case ModuleA:
        concreteModule = new(moduleA.ModuleA)
    }

    err := json.Unmarshal(rawModuleAttributes, concreteModule)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, "", fmt.Errorf("could not unmarshal moduleAttributes")
    }

    return concreteModule, taskModuleTypeCasted, nil
}
```

I get an error because now `moduleA` doesn't fulfill the `Module` interface since it wants to use `T` instead of `ModuleAInputs`.

Is it possible to have each "implementation" of `Module.Run()` take in a type from the `Inputs` union, or do does every `Run` have to be strictly `Run(moduleInput T)` ?

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. please provide an [mre]. The short answer is that yes, "every Run have to be strictly Run(moduleInput T)", if you instantiate `Module` with `T`, and you achieve that by implementing it with a struct which is also parametrized in `T`. Otherwise you can instantiate the interface with a concrete type. Since the function `ConvertDynamicModule` is generic, you should probably use a generic Module struct too. The linked Q&A shows the principle.

Comment: How do i instantiate the interface with a concrete type when said type is unknown, as in the correct concrete type to instantiate with needs to be determined programmatically

Comment: As I said, you should instantiate both with `T`

Comment: I see. Since every ‘Run()’ must be strictly ‘Run(moduleType T)’ would you agree that it’s simpler to just use ‘interface{}’ instead?

Comment: if your ultimate goal is to unmarshal json, yes, it's likely simpler to use `interface{}`